# Where can I find plug sockets in Riga Airport (RIX)?

Tags: electronic-items, power, rix

I just arrived in Riga (B gates, Air Baltic area) and have walked around the terminal a bit without seeing any plug sockets--a bit surprising, since the airport seems quite modern or at least recently renovated.

Are there any plug sockets in Riga Airport available to departing passengers? If so, where are they?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple (literally: I saw 2) publicly accessible sockets in the primary B terminal, which is nice and modern but very crowded; both of the sockets I saw were in use, which isn't surprising because there were probably a couple hundred people in the terminal.

However, but there are **many more sockets in the A terminal**, which is older, dirty, and only has four gates, but was almost completely empty (I had my choice of 10 or so sockets close to seating).

Comment: As part of my "travel kit" I always bring a splitter and an extension cord. It's quite common at airports, hotels, and anywhere to not have enough plugs, or to have plugs that aren't close enough.